# Having trouble getting widget to display milliseconds

Tags: c++, time, widget

So I've been recreating a gamemode that Maiet made for gunz, called spymode. I have most of the inner workings finished, but I'm having trouble with a time display widget. I need it to display time in Minutes, Seconds, and Milliseconds (using int, not float). Minutes & Seconds work correctly, but the millisecond widget is always 0. Here's the code:

```
DWORD dwLimitTime = ZGetGameClient()->GetMatchStageSetting()->GetStageSetting()->nLimitTime;//Gets the TimeLimit for the map
                if (dwLimitTime != 99999) //if not unlimited time
                {
                    dwLimitTime *= 60000;
                    if (dwTime <= dwLimitTime) //dwTime gets time remaining
                    {
                        dwTime = (dwLimitTime - dwTime) / 1000;

                        sprintf(szBuffer, "%02d,%02d,%02d", (dwTime / 60), (dwTime % 60), (dwTime % 60) / 1000); //Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds
                        pBmNumLabel->SetText(szBuffer);//just a char
                        pBmNumLabel->GetBoundsAlignment(); // Gets X/Y coordinates from xml
                        dwLastSpyUpdate = timeGetTime() + 500; //dwLastSpyUpdate is just a generic unsigned long.
                    }
                }
```

I was wondering if anyone knows why the milliseconds aren't being displayed in the timer, and how I could go about fixing it. If more information is requires let me know & I can paste the entire function. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dwTime = (dwLimitTime - dwTime) / 1000;
```

In this line, the division truncates milliseconds from dwTime.

You probably want to have dwTime be in milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: Ty, forgot that integers truncate anything below 1. It's working now. :)